# Поместить объекты в список Retrofit 2

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2

Как добавить имена объекта в список для дальнейшего отображения через свой адаптер. Вот сам API который я получаю с помощью Retrofit 2
[image: Список запроса]

Далее я делаю запрос следующего вида:

> TestHero.kt

```
data class TestHero (@SerializedName("global") val global: PlayerInf,
                     @SerializedName("legends")val legends: AllLegends)

data class  PlayerInf (val name: String, val uid: Long, val avatar: String, val platform: String,
val  level: Int, val toNextLevelPercent: Int, val internalUpdateCount: Int, val bans: BanInf, val rank: RankInf)

data class BanInf (val isActive: Boolean, val remainingSeconds: Int)

data class RankInf (val rankScore: Int, val rankName: String, val rankDiv: Int, val rankImg: String)

data class AllLegends (val all: Revenant)

data class Revenant (val ImgAssets: String)
data class Horizon (val data : ArrayList<Rang>, val ImgAssets: String)

data class Rang (val t0 : String)
```

Тоесть мне нужно создать каждый объект `Revenant, Horizon, Crypto` и т.д. Но я не понимаю как эти имена отобразить в адаптере в textView

> HeroesAdapter.kt

```
class HeroesAdapter(context: Context, heroes: List<TestHero>): BaseAdapter() {
    private val context = context
    private val heroes = heroes

    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return heroes.count()
    }

    override fun getItem(position: Int): Any {
        return heroes[position]
    }

    override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
        return 0
    }

    override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View {

           // categoryView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.activity_heroes, null)
        val listheroView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list_hero_view, parent, false)
           // val categoryImage: ImageView = categoryView.findViewById(R.id.heroesImageView)
            val heroText: TextView = listheroView.findViewById(R.id.textHeroView)
            val category = heroes[position]

            heroText.text = category.legends.all.toString()
            return listheroView

    }
}
```

В отображении получаю следующее:
[image: Ответ в ListView]

Пример того что я хочу получить:
[image: List]

Где я после нажатия буду получать уже данные из **data**

[JSON-API](http://bridge?version=5&platform=PC&player=Ethernetss&auth=Gxbp4SE2e5kScsUmwevA)

```
"legends": {
        "selected": {
            "LegendName": "Octane",
            "data": [
                {
                    "name": "Special event kills",
                    "value": 815,
                    "key": "specialEvent_kills"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Special event wins",
                    "value": 37,
                    "key": "specialEvent_wins"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Special event damage",
                    "value": 321873,
                    "key": "specialEvent_damage"
                }
            ],
            "gameInfo": {
                "skin": "Arachnoid Rush",
                "skinRarity": "Legendary",
                "frame": "Shark Teeth",
                "frameRarity": "Legendary",
                "pose": "All. Day.",
                "poseRarity": "Rare",
                "intro": "Death catches up to everyone",
                "introRarity": "Rare",
                "badges": [
                    {
                        "name": "Venomous",
                        "value": 0,
                        "category": "Octane"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Wild Frontier Level: Season 1",
                        "value": 112,
                        "category": "Account Badges"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Fortune's Favor Level: Season 5",
                        "value": 113,
                        "category": "Account Badges"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "ImgAssets": {
                "icon": "https:\/\/api.mozambiquehe.re\/assets\/icons\/octane.png",
                "banner": "https:\/\/api.mozambiquehe.re\/assets\/banners\/octane.jpg"
            }
        },
        "all": {
            "Revenant": {
                "ImgAssets": {
                    "icon": "https:\/\/api.mozambiquehe.re\/assets\/icons\/revenant.png",
                    "banner": "https:\/\/api.mozambiquehe.re\/assets\/banners\/revenant.jpg"
                }
            },
            "Crypto": {
                "ImgAssets": {
                    "icon": "https:\/\/api.mozambiquehe.re\/assets\/icons\/crypto.png",
                    "banner": "https:\/\/api.mozambiquehe.re\/assets\/banners\/crypto.jpg"
                }
            },
            "Horizon": {
                "data": [
                    {
                        "name": "Season 7 wins",
                        "value": 1,
                        "key": "wins_season_7",
                        "rank": {
                            "rankPos": 59006,
                            "topPercent": 69.87
                        },
                        "rankPlatformSpecific": {
                            "rankPos": 53782,
                            "topPercent": 69.14
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Special event kills",
                        "value": 101,
                        "key": "specialEvent_kills",
                        "rank": {
                            "rankPos": 77442,
                            "topPercent": 64.21
                        },
                        "rankPlatformSpecific": {
                            "rankPos": 52573,
                            "topPercent": 60.51
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Special event damage",
                        "value": 47004,
                        "key": "specialEvent_damage",
                        "rank": {
                            "rankPos": 74182,
                            "topPercent": 57.92
                        },
                        "rankPlatformSpecific": {
                            "rankPos": 51199,
                            "topPercent": 54.54
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "ImgAssets": {
                    "icon": "https:\/\/api.mozambiquehe.re\/assets\/icons\/horizon.png",
                    "banner": "https:\/\/api.mozambiquehe.re\/assets\/banners\/horizon.jpg"
                }
            },
```

Comment: Не очень понятен вопрос. Возможно, вам что-то такое нужно: `heroText.text = category.legends.all.ImgAssets`

Comment: @ЮрийСПб добрый день, нет мне нужно получить имена из объекта `all` а именно *Revenant* *Crypto* *Horizon* *Gibraltar* *Wattson* и т.д. Затем я выгружаю это в Listview и по нажатии на имя я хочу получить массив данных `data` и выгрузить в отдельное активити данные по данному игровому персонажу.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб просто проблема в том что эти имена в данном API оформлены как объекты, и ретрофит ругается если я пытаюсь засунуть в `all` массив данных. Говорит что я должен получить объект вместо массива данных

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Я вот подумал, может сделать просто отдельный список с именами ? тогда как мне его потом привязать к получаемым данным ? Вообщем буду рад любой идее или решению, спасибо

Comment: Мне всё ещё не понятна суть ваших затруднений. Возможно, вы неправильно Json парсите. Кажется, у вас в AllLegents классе должен быть Horizon а в нём массив некой data.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Что бы в ListView отобразить просто название персонажа "Horizon" А если я через аll обращаюсь тогда получаю то что на скрине выше. Постараюсь сделать скрин что я хочу получить

Comment: Дополнил данные того что хочу получить

Comment: Т.е. вам надо не распечатывать toString() класса а какую-то свою строку подставить? Коли так и всегда одна и та же английская строка подойдёт - то можно так, видимо, написать: `heroText.text = category.legends.all::class.simpleName`. Если надо как-то гибче - составьте строку сами, вручную, по условию, например, конкретного класса. Например так: `val string = if(category.legends.all is Revenant) "Revenant" else "Unexpected type"`

Comment: И лучше бы вы дополнили вопрос JSON-ом в текстовом виде вместо непонятного неполного скриншота)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб А как я обращаясь к одному обьекту `all` подключу все остальные ?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Добавил ссылку на Json

Comment: Вам, наверное, надо просто переменные в класс добавить. А то вы классы объявили, но не добавили. По незнакомой ссылке ходить не буду - добавьте текстом в вопрос, не ссылкой.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Обновил

Comment: Может проще сервисом типа json2kotlin.com воспользоваться? Вы явно в этой структуре не ориентируетесь и сами ее не напишете.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja Я структуру понимаю, я только учу retrofit и android в целом, поэтому да, мне некоторые нюансы не ясны, поэтому и спрашиваю у знающих людей в этой области совета, мне просто нужно вывести список имён в столбик 1. Revenant 2. Crypto 3. Horizon 4. 5. 6. 7..... и т.д. список равен количеству персонажей, единственное я не понимаю как в all закинуть все эти объекты и выгрузить потом только имена, а по клику на нужного персонажа я сделаю переход на другое активити для отображения полной информации которая хранится в `data`

Comment: У вас именованный список однотипных объектов не определённой заранее длины? Два варианта: 1) парсить его в `Map` (то есть тип объекта `all: Map<Person>`, ключи мапы будут именами), дальше можно отображать ключи и по ним брать из мапы подробности или конвертировать в список; 2) написать `TypeAdapter` для `all`, в котором имена объектов присвоить дополнительному полю.

Comment: @woesss Спасибо за подсказку. Распарсил в ```map``` оформите как ответ и я наконец-то закрою эту тему.

Comment: Для полноценного ответа нужен код - а я далёк от котлина. Ответьте себе сами)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для реализации моего решения, спасибо @woesss за подсказку, спарсил данные в `Map`

```
data class AllLegends (@SerializedName("all") val all: Map<String, LegendWrapper> = emptyMap())


data class LegendWrapper(
    val data: List<PlayerPerformance>? = emptyList()

)
data class PlayerPerformance(val name: String, val value: Int, val key: String)

data class TestList (val name: ArrayList<String>)
```

далее отобразил это всё в RecyclerView, посмотреть реализацию можно [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1319937/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%B2-recyclerview/1319974?noredirect=1#comment2331259_1319974)